# General way to convert python objects to dicts and other serializations

Tags: python, serialization, dictionary

I am writing a class that stores data that I ultimately want to serialize/deserialize to/from disk. Any object of this class can be unambiguously represented as a dictionary containing the data stored in the object’s attributes. Therefore, serializing and deserializing amounts to converting the object to a dictionary representation (or initializing a new object with the dictionary representation), then serializing/deserializing the dict with something like json.dump(), json.read(), etc.

Calling `obj.__dict__` isn’t acceptable because I’m wrapping the public attributes with `@property` decorators to build in write-once functionality, and storing the actual values in non-public variables like `_attribute`. Therefore, calling `obj.__dict__` returns a dictionary with keys like “_attribute” which isn’t what I want.

What is the “right” way to architect such a class? Should I have an `obj.to_dict()` method (possibly non-public), or write the class such that `dict(obj)` works? Extending the question, should I have an `obj.json_dumps()` method, or write the class such that `json.dumps(obj)` works?

My initial thought was to use the `__repr__` method to create the dict representation of the object, then return the string representation of the dict, but it seems like that approach takes one too many steps. According to a previous [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), `__repr__` should be an unambiguous representation of the object, so I’m happy with `__repr__` returning the string representation of a dict, but converting dict -> str -> dict seems like a non-optimal way to go.

I’m trying to avoid a bad architectural pattern, and I’d also like to have the most general architecture possible so that I can trivially implement some other kind of serialization like yaml or pickle in the future.

Comment: Why not just use `pickle` now?

Answer (score 2):

I might be understanding you wrong but, have you considered [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as ff:
      json.dump(obj, ff)
with open(output_file) as ff:
      obj = json.load(ff)
```

Another option might be the module [PICKLE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

```
with open("mierda.txt", 'w') as ff:
     pickle.dump(a, ff)
with open("mierda.txt") as ff: 
     obj = pickle.load(ff)
```

Comment: I've considered both json and pickle. My question is: what is the most pythonic way to do things? Should I write my class so that it is compatible with those modules, or should my class have methods like, e.g., `obj.json_dump()`?

Comment: Then obviously I'm missing something... How exactly would you need to write your class "to be compatible" with JSON? I'd just write a method "save(file)" (or similar) that calls json.dump on self and another one "read(file)" that calls json.load on the file.